# How do I resize app icons in applications overview on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: icons, gnome-shell

Is there any way to resize these app icons in Ubuntu 18.04?

They seem too big to me.

[image: gnome dash icons]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You can edit `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css`.

   Don't forget to make a backup of the original file!
2. Search for a line starting with `#dash {`.
3. In the following lines you can change the properties like `.icon-grid { spacing` and `icon-grid .overview { icon-size`.
4. After your changes you have to restart the Gnome Shell with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and typing `r` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: in 19.10 I had to edit the file: /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css

Comment: How about 20.04, has anyone found where the file is?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for this info. On my system 18.04 I have found you only need change `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`

And only the line:

```
/* App Vault/Grid */
.icon-grid {
  spacing: 30px; 
  -shell-grid-horizontal-item-size: 96px; /* change this line - was 136px */
  -shell-grid-vertical-item-size: 136px; } 
  .icon-grid .overview-icon {
    icon-size: 96px; }
```

Answer (score 2):

I just managed to change the size in Ubuntu 20.04.1. When using a custom theme the .css is in that file. So Home/.themes.

I changed:

- shell-grid-horizontal-item-size: 86 px
- shell-grid-vertical-item-size: 60 px;
  With the same number the icons are out of shape.

I use the gnome extension for 10 columns.
So much better !!!

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. The file to edit might be `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`, not `gnome-shell.css`. At least this is my case for a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 install.
2. You are still "stuck" with a max of 6 columns. If you want more, then use the "*More columns in applications view*" extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1305/more-columns-in-applications-view/