# How to reduce icon size in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, icons

I have a clean 18.04 install (not update from previous version), the icons in desktop and Show Applications are huge, how can I reduce it. I've tried to go to Nautilus, but I couldn't reduce it to below 50%, I found a solution, but it's for 16.04 ([Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 LTS reduce icon size](https://askubuntu.com/questions/785620/ubuntu-gnome-16-04-lts-reduce-icon-size)), is it the same for 18.04? Will this solution reduce only icons in Show Applications? TIA.

Comment: Do these links help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049325/how-do-i-resize-dash-app-icons-ubuntu-18-04/1049334#1049334  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030016/how-to-scale-the-enormously-sized-desktop-icons-in-gnome-3-28

Comment: Thanks abu_bua, I'll give a try on the 1st solution, the 2nd I've tried and I'm at the maximum (50%), and can't go below that.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure if I'm doing it right, but I reduced the icon-size to half, but didn't work, there're over 20 entries with icon-size, so I'm not sure if I'm changing the right one.