# How can I resize dash app icons on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: icons

The duplicate question was the same, how to resize the app icons. But the answers did not work for me. From my home setting on Terminal I pasted:
/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css
and got the response;
bash: /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css: Permission denied
I tried the other answer and pasted:
/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css
and got the same response;
bash: /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css: Permission denied

Comment: `gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.icon-view thumbnail-size 'your-size' `

Comment: run this cmnd for going back to default `gsettings reset org.gnome.nautilus.icon-view thumbnail-size`

Comment: but it will increase thumbnail-size in nautilus window also.

Comment: I tried the first command and 'your-size' was not recognized. So I took that out and received: Usage:
  gsettings [--schemadir SCHEMADIR] set SCHEMA[:PATH] KEY VALUE

Set the value of KEY to VALUE

Arguments:
  SCHEMADIR A directory to search for additional schemas
  SCHEMA    The name of the schema
  PATH      The path, for relocatable schemas
  KEY       The key within the schema
  VALUE     The value to set

Comment: replace `your-size` with 24 or 48 or 64 any value you prefer

Comment: Sorry but this did not help. I will explain. I do not need help resizing the icons for folders on the desktop nor in Nautilus. (The Ctrl + mouse scroll wheel was a good shortcut idea for that. Thanks.) At the bottom left corner of my dock is a button with nine dots arranged 3X3. It identifies itself with the mouse pointer as "show applications". When I click that button icons spray over the desktop arranged in 4 rows of 6 small icons which are the packages the I can choose from. Some I can identify (Amazon, LibreOffice, etc.) but the icons are so small. Can they be "thumbnail" size?

Comment: Oh the question is clear and its a duplicate question. You can easily find it in AskUbuntu.. Meanwhile me or someother will paste the link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resize dash app icons Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049325/how-do-i-resize-dash-app-icons-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: As I commented above, the Ctrl + mouse scroll wheel was a good shortcut idea for resizing the folder icons on the desktop and in Nautilus. But that is not my problem. I want to increase the size of the app icons. I was directed to a duplicate question with 3 answers. I copied and pasted all of the command line variations in the answers and always get the response, "Permission denied"

Answer (score 0):

In nautilus, the minimum size of 48px is hard-coded within their software. The setting that control this is:

You can see by running this command it's already set to small, so it can't get smaller:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.nautilus.icon-view default-zoom-level
```

Now, depending on your preference, you can set the zoom level by altering the value within the quotes from the list of values listed below

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.icon-view default-zoom-level 'value'
```

- small
- standard
- large
- larger
- largest

For fine grain control, use

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.icon-view thumbnail-size 100
```

Replace `100` with your desired size