# How to change icon size in "Show Applications"?

Tags: icons

I used Ubuntu 20.04, I want bigger icon in "Show Applications", but I haven't found somewhere to change it  - in the "Settings - Appearance", one could only change the icon size on desktop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resize app icons in applications overview on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049325/how-do-i-resize-app-icons-in-applications-overview-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: I found only "Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource" under my "theme" folder, no "gnome-shell.css" or "ubuntu.css".